# How to hide body of gridpanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, gridpanel

My grid have some docked toolbars and i want to hide only grid body.
I tried to hide like this:

```
mygrid.body.hide();
```

rows disappeared but container height not changed. So instead grid rows I got empty space..

So how can I collapse and expand gridpanel body?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `doLayout()` and/or `doComponentLayout()` on grid

Comment: in firebug i see that style has changed(highlighted) so somehow extjs counts and hidden elements heights?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

- Hide the headercontainer of the grid with hide(), if needed (this contains the grid header row)
- Hide the body of the grid with hide() as you did.
- Set the height of grid to appropriate value: grid.setHeight(grid_header_height + grid_toolbar_height). Plus grid_headercontainer_height to if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
mygrid.collapse();
```

Comment: This also would collapse docked toolbars